# Rails unable to generate instance variable in class initialize method to generate httparty request

Tags: ruby, httparty

I'm having issues generating a `Signature` via a Ruby class. When I go into my docker container, I'm able to see that all the instance variables in the `initialize` method are `nil` expect the `@api_key` variable.

I have the following class

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

module SeamlessGov
  class Form
    include HTTParty
    attr_accessor :form_id
    base_uri "https://nycopp.seamlessdocs.com/api"

    def initialize()
      @api_key = ENV['SEAMLESS_GOV_API_KEY']
      @signature = generate_signature
      @form_id = ENV['SEAMLESS_GOV_FORM_ID']
      @timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
    end

    def relative_uri
      "/form/#{@form_id}/elements"
    end

    def create_form
      self.class.get(relative_uri, headers: generate_headers)
    end

    private

    def generate_signature
      OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', ENV['SEAMLESS_GOV_SECRET'], "GET+#{relative_uri}+#{@timestamp}")
      binding.pry
    end

    def generate_headers
      {
        "Authorization"  => "HMAC-SHA256 api_key='#{@api_key}' signature='#{@timestamp}'",
         Net::HTTP::ImmutableHeaderKey.new('AuthDate') => "#{@timestamp}"
      }
    end
  end
end
```

As you see, from the `binding.pry` in the `generate_signature` method I'm able to see the instance variables:[image]

The `relative_uri` method needed to generate the signature doesn't load the `@form_id` variable in the string.

Here is the controller:

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
  def display_form
    @form = SeamlessGov::Form.new().create_form
  end
end
```

Work around `net/http` headers case sensitivity:
`lib/net_http`

```
require 'net/http'

class Net::HTTP::ImmutableHeaderKey
  attr_reader :key

  def initialize(key)
    @key = key
  end

  def downcase
    self
  end

  def capitalize
    self
  end

  def split(*)
    [self]
  end

  def hash
    key.hash
  end

  def eql?(other)
    key.eql? other.key.eql?
  end

  def to_s
    def self.to_s
      key
    end
    self
  end
end
```

If I call `create_form` this is the output:

```
{"error"=>true,
 "error_log"=>
  [{"error_code"=>"missing_date_headers",
    "error_message"=>"Request is missing date headers",
    "error_description"=>
     "{\"Host\":\"nycopp.seamlessdocs.com\",\"Connection\":\"close\",\"X-Real-IP\":\"71.249.243.7\",\"X-Forwarded-For\":\"71.249.243.7\",\"X-Forwarded-Host\":\"nycopp.seamlessdocs.com\",\"X-Forwarded-Port\":\"443\",\"X-Forwarded-Proto\":\"https\",\"X-Original-URI\":\"\\/api\\/form\\/\\/elements\",\"X-Scheme\":\"https\",\"Authorization\":\"HMAC-SHA256 api_key='h123xxxxxxxxxx' signature=''\",\"AuthDate\":\"\"}"},
   {"error_code"=>"external_auth_error", "error_message"=>"Date header is missing or timestamp out of bounds"}]}
```

What is the issue?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I just updated the post with the output to the `create_form` method. Only the `api_key` is shown.

Comment: Ah, I see now. You generate signature before the other parameters are set. But api key is set already, that's why it's the only thing you see.

Comment: Replace that screenshot with text. There's never a good reason to post code as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in the order of operations/calculations.

```
def initialize()
  @api_key = ENV['SEAMLESS_GOV_API_KEY']
  @signature = generate_signature # <= at this point, neither form_id nor timestamp are set. but api key is.
  @form_id = ENV['SEAMLESS_GOV_FORM_ID']
  @timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
end
```